# jstree: checkboxes are only shown with jquery.jstree.js

Tags: jquery, jstree

I downloaded Jstree, made a simple example (by pointing to the 6 local jstree files) and it worked fine.
But adding checkbox to the list of plugins doesn't show me the checkboxes.
If I instead download the file jquery.jstree.js and point to it, then the checkboxes are shown.

A similar problem was already addressed:
[jsTree: loading the jquery.jstree.js file from an app dir behaves differently from loading it from a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4822194/jstree-loading-the-jquery-jstree-js-file-from-an-app-dir-behaves-differently-fro)
but the proposed solution (correctly unzip the files) still doesn't work for me.

Do you have any idea?
I use the latest jsquery (1.6.2) and latest jtree (pre1.0stable or 4649941.zip).
Thanks,
Ralph

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm which version you are using in the case where it works and it doesn't?  You might want to try the [v1.0rc2 version](http://code.google.com/p/jstree/downloads/detail?name=jsTree.v.1.0rc2.zip&can=2&q=) of jstree.  Just name it slightly differently and put it in the same directory that the pre1.0stable version is in, so that the themes folder is in the right place.

I would try version 1.6.1 of jQuery or lower - there seems to be issues with 1.6.2.